# Tablet with Windows 10: keyboard doesn't appear in TextBox

Tags: winforms, textbox, keyboard, windows-10, tablet

I have a `WinForms` application. The problem is that a virtual keyboard doesn't appear when I enter the `TextBox` on my tablet with Windows 10. I also have some `TextBox` to enter password (with `PasswordChar` property set). In that `TextBox` virtual keyboard appears correctly.

So, to make the experiment clear I made a sample `WinForms` application and added a few `TextBox` on the `Form`, one of them for entering password (with `PassowordChar` property set). And it appears that even in a clear sample application virtual keyboard didn't appear for usual `TextBox` and appeared for `PasswordChar` `TextBox`.

So, can I fix the problem in any way?
Or should I just wait for some updates?

Comment: Is the device currently set in Tablet Mode? If it's not, does it make a difference when you switch? You can find more about Tablet Mode [here](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2015/07/18/how-to-use-tablet-mode-in-windows-10/)